# Propagation of State Monad

Tags: haskell, state, monads

I have the following function for walking around "edges" of the "graph" of my game world. It alters the state of the world--specifically, the player's location. I need to report a message alerting the player of their change in location as well.

So I could either return a tuple of (message, newWorld), or I could use a State monad. (Right? I'm new to this stuff.)

Here's my attempt at the monad approach:

```
walk dir = do
  world <- get
  let attempt = filter (\e -> edgeDirection e == dir) $ edges
      edges = (worldEdges world) M.! playerLoc
      playerLoc = playerLocation $ worldPlayer world
  case attempt of
    [] -> return "You can't go that way."
    (edge : _) -> do
      put world' 
      return message
        where world' = world { worldPlayer = player' }
              player' = (worldPlayer world) { playerLocation = loc }
              loc = edgeLocation edge
              message = "You go " ++ (downcase $ show dir)
```

The thing is, now the function that *calls* `walk` has a State monad to deal with. Do I `runState` it right there, or do I have that function use State monads too, like this:

```
parseWalk dir =
  let direction = case dir of
                  ('e' : _) -> Just East
                  ('n' : _) -> Just North
                  ('s' : _) -> Just South
                  ('w' : _) -> Just West
                  ('u' : _) -> Just Up
                  ('d' : _) -> Just Down
                  _         -> Nothing
  in case direction of
    Just d -> walk d
    Nothing -> return "You can't go that way"
```

Then what about `parseWalk`'s caller, and so forth? Should I try to keep this State monad passed around as long as possible? Should I be seeing a lot of `MonadState ...` in my type signatures?

Comment: Since you're walking and modifiying a large data structure, you may want to look at using a Zipper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of thinking about it: `runState` requires an initial state as its parameter. Where is this initial state available in your code? That's how far the state monad needs to propagate.

Note that `runState` encapsulates the stateful computation, so that if you have two `runState` computations side-by-side, they won't see each other's states (unless you pass the result from one to the other.) This also should give you a hint how far "up" the `runState` needs to be.