# Stuck in the State Monad

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I want to create a graph structure using an IntMap of nodes and unique keys. This topic has been covered well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12941625/ids-from-state-monad-in-haskell?lq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6311512/creating-unique-labels-in-haskell). I understand how the state monad works by basically wrapping a function of state -> (val,state) in a newtype so we can create a monad instance for it. I have read about the topic quite a bit. I still cant seem to get my head around how I can get unique (or just incremental) values throughout the execution of my program. It's easy enough to get a run of successive IDs, but once I "runState" to get out of the monad it seems like I'm back where I started with having to keep track of the current ID. I feel like I'm stuck in the monad. The other option I considered was to keep the entire IntMap and current "next" ID as the state, but that seems very "imperative" and extreme. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385363/propogation-of-state-monad) question is very similar but did not get many answers(or maybe I'm just missing something obvious). What is the idiomatic way to utilize the state monad to get unique ID throughout a program execution? Thanks.

Comment: Actually the more I think about it, the idea of encapsulating the entire map in a monad sounds appealing. I would like to write functions that use the ID (or map key) like the actual value, instead of having to "lookup" constantly. But, it's also late and I work with C++ all day so maybe I'm not thinking clearly.

Comment: I think the real question is why you feel you have to do something "outside" of `runState`. The only situation where you couldn't just push `runState` outwards instead is when you want access to a shadowed "outer" monad (say, IO). At that point you need transformers, as Gabriel suggests.

Comment: @Peter, Yes it seems this is the real issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let's imagine we were to `IO`-ify the `State` monad.  What would that look like?  Our pure `State` monad is just a newtype around:

```
s -> (a, s)
```

Well, the `IO` version might do a little bit of side effects before returning the final values, which would look like:

```
s -> IO (a, s)
```

That pattern is so common it has a name, specifically `StateT`:

```
newtype StateT s m a = StateT { runStateT :: s -> m (a, s) }
```

The name has a `T` at the end because it is a monad `T`ransformer.  We call `m` the "base monad" and `StateT s m` the "transformed" monad.

`StateT s m` is only a `Monad` if `m` is a `Monad`:

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (StateT s m) where {- great exercise -}
```

However, in addition to that, all monad transformers implement the `MonadTrans` class, defined as follows:

```
class MonadTrans t where
    lift :: (Monad m) => m a -> t m a

instance MonadTrans (StateT s) where {- great exercise -}
```

If `t` is `StateT s`, then `lift`'s type specializes to:

```
lift :: m a -> StateT s m a
```

In other words, it lets us "lift" an action in the base monad to become an action in the transformed monad.

So, for your specific problem, you want the `StateT (IntMap k v) IO` monad, which extends `IO` with additional `State`.  Then you can write your entire program in this monad:

```
main = flip runStateT (initialState :: IntMap k v) $ do
    m <- get        -- retrieve the map
    lift $ print m  -- lift an IO action
    (k, v) <- lift readLn
    put (insert k v m)
```

Notice that I still use `get` and `put`.  That's because the `transformers` package implements all the concepts I described and it generalizes the signatures of `get` and `put` to be:

```
get :: (Monad m) => StateT s m s
put :: (Monad m) => s -> StateT s m ()
```

That means they automatically work within `StateT`.  `transformers` then just defines `State` as:

```
type State s = StateT s Identity
```

That means that you can use `get` and `put` for both `State` and `StateT`.

To learn more about monad transformers, I highly recommend [Monad Transformers - Step by Step](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf).

Comment: As always, an answer stuffed with wisdom. Thanks Gabriel, I'll have to process for a bit and see what the implications are for my application.

Comment: That was the perfect paper for me to read right now. I knew I was going to have to dig into Monad Transformers at some point, I just didn't realize how soon.

Comment: @MFlamer Yeah, Haskell is all about composing solutions from small building blocks.  If monads are language building blocks (i.e. state, error handling, io), then monad transformers are composable building blocks (literally: assembling monad transformers is composition where monad transformers are monad morphisms between monad objects).  When you build your own monad transformer stack, you are basically picking and choosing which language features you want to incorporate, unlike other languages which make the choice for you.