# Unique id/counter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I am trying to generate some assembly instructions in Haskell and need to generate some unique ids to label sections for `jmp` instructions. I believe I could do this using a state monad but I am still new to Haskell and not super comfortable with State monad and need some help using it in this context.

Here is one of the examples where I'd need a unique id

```
generateExpression :: AST.Expr -> String
generateExpression (AST.BinOpExpr AST.Or e1 e2) =
            (generateExpression e1) ++
            "    cmpl    $0, %eax\n" ++
            "    je      _or_clause2\n" ++
            "    movl    $1, %eax\n" ++
            "    jmp     _or_end\n" ++
            "_or_clause2:\n" ++           -- need to use a unique id here instead of clause 2
            (generateExpression e2) ++
            "    cmpl    $0, %eax\n" ++
            "    movl    $0, %eax\n" ++
            "    setne   %al\n" ++
            "_or_end:\n"                  -- need to use a unique id here to label the end
```

Edit: I have read some tutorials on State Monad and can implement a simple counter such as

```
import Control.Monad.State

counter :: State Int Int
counter = do
    x <- get
    put (x+1)
    return x

runState counter 1 -- outputs (1,2) where the state has been incremented
```

which would keep track of a counter as the state. But I am not sure how to use this in my function where I need to keep a state around in recursive calls.

Comment: Did you read any tutorials such as [this one](https://wiki.haskell.org/State_Monad) or [this one](https://mmhaskell.com/monads-5)? What point did you get stuck at? Did you look at the [haddock](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-13.23/transformers-0.5.6.2/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html) documentation? Related: [Stuck in the State Monad](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14516835/2682729)

Comment: I did read some tutorials and various references. I think I understand how to implement a simple counter but not sure how to use it in my function. (edited the post with a little more clarification)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the return type needs to have a `State Int` in it, it can't be `String`. The key thing is that you need to thread the State through. Here, I've used `do` notation as you seem comfortable with it.

```
counter :: State Int Int
counter = do
    n <- get
    put (n + 1)
    pure n

generateASM :: AST.Expr -> State Int String
generateASM (AST.BinOpExpr AST.Or e1 e2) = do
    e1ASM <- generateASM e1
    n <- counter
    e2ASM <- generateASM e2
    pure $
        e1ASM ++
        "    cmpl    $0, %eax\n" ++
        "    je      _or_clause" ++ show n ++ "\n" ++
        "    movl    $1, %eax\n" ++
        "    jmp     _or_end" ++ show n ++ "\n" ++
        "_or_clause" ++ show n ++ ":\n" ++ show n ++
        e2ASM ++
        "    cmpl    $0, %eax\n" ++
        "    movl    $0, %eax\n" ++
        "    setne   %al\n" ++
        "_or_end" ++ show n ++ ":\n"
generateASM (..) = .. -- other branches defined similarly...

generateASMFull :: AST.Expr -> String
generateASMFull e = evalState (generateASM e) 0
```

P.S. I haven't checked if your assembly logic is correct.